# Closing browser tab after redirecting to Playstore

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-play

I'm Redirecting to google play store(The App) in Android Phones via some referral link but I'm unable to close the browser tab after redirection. I tried `window.close()`; but it's not working.

just like here if you click this link in mobile chrome broswer it will prompt up for Android Play store. flipkart.com/mobile-apps

```
<body>
    <script>
        window.location.href = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bt.bms";  
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL= " http:>
    </noscript>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing a tab is not allowed by most browsers. Some will display an alert asking the user if he wants to close the tab.

Can you not simply link to the Google Play Store by using the current tab? Instead of opening a new one?

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bt.bms" target="_self">Download My App</a>
```

The `target="_self"` is the default so its unnecessary.

If you want to just show the Google Playstore in a new tab/window just add a link to your page like this:

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bt.bms" target="_blank">Download My App</a>
```

That will open the Playstore in a new tab.

Comment: I'm Redirecting to google play store(The App) in Android Phones.
like if you click this link in mobile chrome broswer it will peompt up for Android Play store.
http://www.flipkart.com/mobile-apps

Comment: You might want to add that information to your question so everyone can help you better.